# how to check if artifact exists gitlab

Tags: gitlab

in gitlab I have a "job1" that sometimes does not start whatsoever due to various reason and I can't change that. When that job is skipped, then the artifacts for the job is not created.

My question is, is there a way for job2 to check if the artifact from job1 exists?
It is not a question of whether or not we can fix job1 to make it always send the artifact, it is a question of how can I check if the "art.txt" file is there or not

Comment: if job1 not created artifact that job1 status is success or failure ?

Answer (score 1):

if job1 create artifact art.txt fail, job1 status will fail. you can used `dependencies`, when job1 failure job2 will not start, maybe look like:

```
job1:
  stage: stage1
  script:
    - create art.txt
  artifact:
    paths:
      - art.txt

job2:
  stage: stage2
  script:
    - do something.
  dependencies:
    - job1
```

if job1 create artifact art.txt fail, job1 status will success. you can check art.txt status used shell script in job2 script section. look lik

```yaml
job2:
  stage: stage2
  script:
    - |
      if [[ -f art.txt ]]; then 
        "is exist";
      else
        "is not exist";
        exit 1;
      fi;

  dependencies:
    - job1
```