# Gitlab: execute stage conditionally depends on a new file generated on previous stage or not

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: python:3.10

stages:
  - build
  - notify

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "run build"
    - line=$(cat faulty_links.txt | wc -l |xargs)
    - echo $line
    - if [ ${line} -gt "0" ]; then echo $line > found_fault_links; fi
    - ls -l
  artifacts:
    untracked: true

notify:
  stage: notify
  dependencies:
    - build
  script:
    - echo "notify"
  rules:
    - exists:
      - found_fault_links
```

So ideally, in stage `build`, when detect there are contents in `faulty_links.txt`, I create a new file called `found_fault_links`

I used command `ls -l`, I can see the file `found_fault_links` created.

In stage `notify`, if file `found_fault_links` is exist, It will run the notify stage. If not, ignore this stage.

But when I run this pipeline, only stage `build` is run, never run the second stage.

How to fix this issue?

**I don't have to follow this way, maybe there are better ways, please recommend as well**

Comment: Have you checked this? https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/215100

Comment: You could also check this as a workaround - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70218023/how-to-check-if-artifact-exists-gitlab